# How to revoke a client certificate in WCF?

Tags: c#, wcf, ssl, certificate

I'm developing a self-hosting WCF Service with this scenario:

```
wsHttpbinding
*Transport security layer
Client Credential = Certificate
```

I created a self-signed RootCA certificate and a "www.server.com" and a "www.client.com" certificates issued by the RootCA certificate.

*This is the client environment configuration:*
I need to install the RootCA public key in the Trusted Root Certification Authorities store and the www.client.com certificate in My store.

Like this everything is working.

But my question is, in this scenario described in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731074(v=vs.110).aspx) example the www.client.com public key should not be in the TrustedPeople store of the server machine too? Because if I want to exclude a client I should have the control on the server side. Theres some configuration on WCF that allow me do that?

ps: In the MSDN link above, in the first paragraph theres this quote `The server’s certificate must be trusted by the client and the client’s certificate must be trusted by the server.` But this is not working.

Answer (score 1):

I think that in order to fully control client authentication with certificates, you likely need to fully understand the certificate revocation process.  The following article provides a good overview of Certificate Revocation, including the validation chain and CRL caching.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee619754(v=ws.10).aspx

Regarding WCF configuration, you have access to the following config values that control client certificate validation:

```
X509ClientCertificateAuthentication.RevocationMode
X509ServiceCertificateAuthentication.CertificateValidationMode
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.security.x509clientcertificateauthentication.revocationmode(v=vs.110).aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.security.x509servicecertificateauthentication.certificatevalidationmode(v=vs.110).aspx

Regards.

Comment: Yes i know that properties. But the CertificateValidationMode only works with Message Security mode, and not with Transport security mode.